# How to make image downloadable created by xslt from xml?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

```
<img height="75" width="100">
   <xsl:attribute name="src">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('data:JPG;base64,',/Xpath)"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

The image is created from values in XML.
I have created an image using xslt from xml using above code but how to make it downloadable ?

Comment: Sorry, you haven't really given enough information to answer. Likely it's to do with `Content-Type` as rendered by your webserver.

Comment: Content-Type is html

Comment: Then it isn't going to render as an image. But seriously, check out [ask] if you want a useful answer.

Comment: It is rendering as an image

Answer (score 0):

You could create a link to the inline image (with javascript for example):

```
<a target="_blank" href="data:image/png;base64,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">download image</a>
```